# What exactly are warm / hot dishes?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-requests

I have an issues understanding the definition of **warm dishes**, specifically:

1. Are soups included into warm dishes?
2. If yes how do we call dishes that are not fluid?

For example:

> A: What kind of food can I eat in your restaraunt?
>   B: We server salads & soups.
>   A: Can I get a **warm dish**?
>   B: No, sorry, we don't have any.

Does this sound idiomatic? Or there is a better world to denote the type of meal that is warm, but not soup or anything fluid?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241806/what-is-a-hot-meal

Comment: Soups like meat, pasta, rice are all dishes, but asking for a "cooked meal" will probably be your best bet.

Comment: In Minnesota a "warm dish" would be a "hot dish" that has almost gotten cold.

Comment: As HotLicks notes, dishes or meals are generally *hot* or *cold* in English; a *warm drink* sounds unappetizing and a *warm meal* sounds vaguely unsafe.

Comment: So, if I said "hot dish", would it include "soups"? Because I am looking for a word that will not include "soups". @choster

Comment: Why don't you explain the reason for excluding soups? Soup is food, it can be made with meat, fish, chicken or vegetables or a combination of any of the aforementioned. It can be thin and golden coloured, or thick brown and lumpy. What has soup ever done bad to you? What makes "soup" unworthy in your eyes?! Soup is the ideal food in nursing homes and in homeless shelters. Learn to embrace soup as food! :P

Comment: @Eduard - Not in Minnesota.  In Minnesota (and much of North Dakota) a "hot dish" is what others would call a "casserole".

Answer (score 1):

One idiomatic phrase is **hot meals**.

Some food, served on a plate for someone to eat, could be called a "dish". And indeed you might see "dish" used that way in restaurants (e.g. Dish Of The Day). But the word "meal" is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what they were actually asking for, they may have been talking about food.

Comment: It is evident from the question that they are talking about food.